# Why to I get a vertical scroll bar on my Flex object ONLY in Firefox and Chrome

Tags: html, flash, apache-flex, google-chrome, scrollbar

Okay, here's one. We're running a SharePoint publishing/public site and I have this URL with a Flash object that displays a table that updates every 5 minutes:

https://www.midwestiso.org/MARKETSOPERATIONS/REALTIMEMARKETDATA/Pages/ExAnteLMP.aspx

Yes, Yes, I know there's a million Ajax ways to do this, but there's politics behind it.

On Firefox and Chrome I get a vertical scroll bar from the browser, not the flash object. There should be NO scroll bar and is none in IE.

I used the page view webpart and the width is set to 700 px and the height is greater than the height on the flash HTML.

So why oh why do I get that Bar?

Answer (score 0):

If the width of the flash object in HTML is wider then the browser window you will get both scroll bars.
set the width of the object in your embed code to 100%

Actually scratch the div wrapping your iframe has a height set to 200 PX so when the content is larger it will trigger the scroll bar 
set overflow="hidden" on the div
The div id is webpartWPQ2

Comment: I'd say go with having a width/height of 100%.  Use SWFObject to embed your Flash.

Comment: In this case his issue is definitely with the div. But yeah swfobject is the way to go.